# getContentLength() returns a different value than in browser

Tags: java, httprequest, httpurlconnection, content-length

I have some images in my server, which I need to download into my app. Before that, I need to show the total size of those images to user. So I send `HEAD` requests to all of those files and get the HTTP header `Content-Length` values and add them up.

The problem is that `HttpURLConnection`'s `getContentLength()` method returns a different value than it shows in browser Inspect Element window. And the issue stays the same when the request method is `GET`.

```
URL url = new URL("https://radio-lanka-rs.firebaseapp.com/imgs/12_20190303.png");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
int size = con.getContentLength(); // 29493
```

above `size` variable gives `29493` but the browsers show that it's `28456`.

Google Chrome

[image: Chrome]

Mozilla Firefox

[image: Firefox]

---

What is causing `getContentLength()` to show an increased value?

Comment: What are all the differences in request and response headers? Is the response gzipped in Java, for example?

Comment: above code shows how I get the response in java. And it's a normal `GET` request for browsers. All request headers are default.

Comment: Java client is probably not negotiating gzip, whereas modern browsers all will.

Comment: Which is why we'd like to see both sets of headers for both environments.